# Create interop dll from .tlb file

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com, tlbimp

I have a C++ project and a c# project. The C# project accesses methods of the C++ project through 2 interop dlls called interop.X.dll and interop.XCom.dll.

When my C++ project rebuilds it creates X.tlb and XCom.tlb files, it also creates x_i.c, x_h.h, xCom_i.c, xCom_h.c files. I have found that the files are created due to project settings in "configuration properties -> MIDL -> output", as displayed below;

[image]

What I need to know is how to create the 2 interop dlls, which doesn't get created automatically, using the .tlb and other c files. I have tried using `tlbimp x.tlb /out:Interop.x.dll`, but the created dll doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just bypass tlb references and instead just add a direct COM reference?

Comment: The projects were not created by me. So I don't want to change them too much.

Comment: Huh?  Adding a COM reference from .NET to your COM library requires **zero change** on the COM project.  Anyway, I thought VS created the interop dlls when you add a COM reference?

Comment: Ok.. How do I add a COM reference to my C++ project, forgive my ignorance but I haven't dealt with COM objects before.

Comment: tlbimp should work, with proper parameters. What doesn't work this tlbimp exactly?

Comment: You put me in the correct path, I was able to add COM references to my C# project and it created the interop dlls for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a summary of my comments above.

---

Why not just bypass tlb references and instead just add a direct COM reference?

Adding a COM reference from .NET to your COM library requires zero change on the COM project. VS creates the interop dlls when you add a COM reference from your .NET project